# Uniqueness of dualizing objects

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, duality

One definition of (symmetric) [star-autonomous category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/star-autonomous+category) is as a closed symmetric monoidal category $(C,\otimes,I,\multimap)$ equipped with an object $\bot$ such that all double-dualization maps $A \to ((A\multimap\bot)\multimap \bot)$ are isomorphisms.  It follows that the functor $A \mapsto (A\multimap \bot)$ is a contravariant autoequivalence of $C$.

Such an object is sometimes called a *dualizing object*, although sometimes that name only requires double-dualization to be an isomorphism when $A$ is suitably "finite".  Here I'm interested in the case where it is an isomorphism for *all* objects $A\in C$.

Can a given closed symmetric monoidal category admit more than one star-autonomous structure, i.e. can there be more than one such object $\bot$?

Comment: You can always twist by a $\otimes$-invertible object. In [DAG-XIV](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/DAG-XIV.pdf#page=97), Lurie proves that this is the only indeterminacy in a class of examples (see 4.2.9 and 4.2.10 there), but it takes a fair amount of work and auxiliary hypotheses. I'm not sure it holds in general.

Comment: @TimCampion You mean that if $\bot$ is dualizing and $V$ is invertible then $V\otimes \bot$ is also dualizing?  I can sort of imagine how that works, but it would be nice to see it written out; can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If a dualizing object exists, there is a bijection between isomorphism classes of dualizing objects and isomorphism classes of $\otimes$-invertible objects (i.e. the Picard group), given by tensoring your favorite dualizing object by a $\otimes$-invertible object. So the groupoid of $\ast$-autonomous structures, if nonempty, is equivalent to the groupoid of $\otimes$-invertible objects (canonically as soon as one chooses a basepoint -- it's a torsor over the grouplike symmetric monoidal groupoid of $\otimes$-invertible objects).

**One direction:**

First let's check that if $D$ is dualizing and $L$ is $\otimes$-invertible (with inverse $L^\vee$), then $L\otimes D$ is dualizing. Write $[,]$ for the internal hom (sorry, I seem to be changing all of your notation :). Then

$\begin{align*}
[[A, L\otimes D], L\otimes D]
&= [L^\vee \otimes [A, L\otimes D], D] \\
&= [L^\vee \otimes L \otimes [A,D],D] \\
&= [[A,D],D] \\
&= A
\end{align*}$

I suppose I should verify that the above isomorphism is the canonical morphism $A \to [[A, L\otimes D], L\otimes D]$, but since all the isomorphisms used were canonical, maybe I'll just wave my hands and ask rhetorically, "what else could it be?".

**The converse:**

In fact, it's always the case that any two dualizing objects differ by tensoring by a $\otimes$-invertible object. Here's a proof.

- First note that if $D$ is dualizing, then $[D,D] = I$. To see this, it suffices to check that $[[D,D],D] = [I,D]$ because $[-,D]$ is a contravariant equivalence of categories. But both sides are $D$, so this is the case.
- Now if $D,D'$ are both dualizing, I claim that $[D,D']$ is $\otimes$-invertible, with inverse $[D',D]$. To see this, it suffices by symmetry to show that $[D,D'] \otimes [D',D] = I$. To check this, it suffices to check that $[[D,D'] \otimes [D',D],D] = [I,D]$. The lefthand side simplifies to $[[D,D'], [[D',D],D]] = [[D,D'],D'] = D$ where we have curried, and then used the dualizing property of both $D$ and $D'$. Of course, this is the same as the righthand side.
- Finally, I claim that $D \otimes [D,D'] = D'$. To see this, it suffices to check that $[D \otimes [D,D'], D'] = [D',D']$. We've already seen that the righthand side is $I$ in the first bullet. And the lefthand side simplifies to $[D, [[D,D'],D']] = [D,D] = I$.

So $D$ and $D'$ differ by tensoring by the $\otimes$-invertible object $[D,D']$.

And of course, since tensoring with a $\otimes$-invertible object is an equivalence of categories, the action map $L \mapsto L \otimes D$ is fully faithful; we've just seen it's essentially surjective, so it's an equivalence of groupoids.

---

**Endnote:**

More than once I've found myself questioning the equation $[A,L\otimes D] = L \otimes [A,D]$ used in the second line of the forward direction so let me just record the proof here for my own benefit:

$\begin{align*}
Hom(X,[A,L\otimes D]) &= Hom(X \otimes A, L\otimes D) \\
&= Hom(X \otimes A \otimes L^\vee, D) \\
&= Hom(X \otimes L^\vee, [A,D]) \\
&= Hom(X, L \otimes [A,D])
\end{align*}$

and conclude by Yoneda. So this isomorphism holds for any dualizable $L$ and arbitrary $A,D$.

Comment: It might be slightly more straightforward to work with $[L,D]$ instead of $L\otimes D$

Comment: Good call! I'll edit that in.

Comment: Or maybe I'll leave it as-is for now. Probably the true measure of how simple a presentation is would be how easy it is to show that the isomorphism is the canonical one, which is eluding me right now.

Comment: Nice, thanks!  In fact, this is one of those magical places where you don't need to show that the isomorphism is the canonical one!  If there's *any* natural isomorphism $A \cong [[A,D],D]$, then the functor $[-,D]$ is an equivalence (since it has both a right and left inverse, namely itself).  Hence since it is also adjoint to itself on the right, the unit and counit of that adjunction are isomorphisms; but those are both the canonical map $A\to [[A,D],D]$, so that is an isomorphism too.

Comment: After all it also would not make much difference since $[L,D]=L^\vee\otimes D$, so this would amount to work with $L^\vee$ instead of $L$

Comment: Let me still type it out:$$A\to[[A,D],D]\to[[L,[A,D]],[L,D]]\to[[A,[L,D]],[L,D]]$$

Comment: If we fix a dualizing object $\bot$, and set $A^\ast := [A,\bot]$, then we have  dual tensor $\&$ defined by $A \&B = (A^\ast \otimes B^\ast)^\ast$ with unit $\bot = I^\ast$. Then the possible dualizing objects $D$ with respect to $\otimes$ are just the invertible objects with respect to $\&$. So one way to phrase all of this is that the Picard groups with respect to $\otimes$ and $\&$ are isomorphic.

Comment: This is spectacular! (I had no idea that such a thing could be true.) I just want to add that, with a small amount of care, the result can be extended to arbitrary (*i.e.*, not necessarily symmetric) $*$-autonomous categories.

Comment: I suppose the catch is that oftentimes we start with a category $C$ of interest, and no dualizing object exists there. Every object $D$ will have a maximal subcategory $C_D \subseteq C$ on which $D$ is dualizing; it's a delicate condition to ensure that $D \in C_D$. And there can be $D,D'$ with $C_D \neq C_{D'}$, even with $D \in C_D$ and $D' \in C_{D'}$ so that we get distinct star-autonomous full monoidal subcategories of $C$. For instance with $D$ the monoidal unit we get the rigid objects, which doesn't preclude the existence of another subcategory with a different dualizing object.