# Strictification for closed monoidal categories

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, coherence

The strictification theorem for monoidal categories states that every monoidal categorically is monoidally equivalent to a strict monoidal category. Is there a strictification theorem for closed monoidal categories? I expect this to take a form similar to the following.

Call a closed monoidal category **strict** if the monoidal structure is strict and the following canonical isomorphisms are identities:
$$[I, X] \cong X$$
$$[X, [Y, Z]] \cong [X \otimes Y, Z]$$

I believe that the first identity should follow from a strictification theorem for [closed categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+category), so that the strictification theorem for closed monoidal categories is the union of the strictification theorems for monoidal categories, closed categories, along with the additional axiom governing the interaction between the monoidal and closed structures given by currying.

This seems like a natural question to ask, and so I would not be surprised to find it in the literature already, but I have not been able to do so.

Comment: I find this unlikely

Comment: I'm reasonably sure it is true, and think I can prove it using a syntactic argument, but there are quite a number of conditions to check, and I would hope there was either a more elegant argument, or a proof already in the literature.

Comment: So, how would you do it for the category of sets? I'm really curious.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind for me is a [theorem of Mike Shulman's](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.08487): every closed monoidal category embeds fully faithfully into a star-autonomous monoidal category. For a star-autonomous category, I'm tempted to say that some sort of strictification theorem will follow from the usual strictification of monoidal categories... It seems relevant that the star-autonomous structure is [almost](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284805/uniqueness-of-dualizing-objects) definable in terms of the monoidal structure.

Comment: @varkor I suppose you must be doing something like this: take the set of objects of the strictification to be the set of formal expressions generated by the set of objects of the original category and the operations $I$, $\otimes$, and $[-, -]$, modulo the equations you want to hold; prove a normal form theorem for this set; then define the morphisms by "pullback" along the "evaluation" from the set of formal expressions to the original set of objects. This certainly sounds like something that should be an instance of a general theorem...

Comment: @TimCampion: that's an interesting approach. [Coherence of the double involution on ∗-autonomous categories](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~hassei/papers/star-tac.pdf) gives a coherence result for (symmetric) *-autonomous categories. Perhaps this can be reflected to give one for symmetric closed monoidal categories (it certainly provides further evidence that a coherence theorem holds).

Comment: @ZhenLin: yes, exactly.

Comment: One possible abstract approach would be to express closed monoidal categories as pseudoalgebras for a 2-monad (on the 2-category of categories, functors, and natural isomorphisms, because there is contravariance) and try to apply a general [strictification theorem for pseudoalgebras for 2-monads](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404902001366).