# $\ast$-autonomous categories with non-invertible dualizing object?

Tags: ct.category-theory, examples, monoidal-categories, duality, symmetric-monoidal-categories

**1. Definition**
Firstly, recall the following [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/star-autonomous+category)-definition of a $\ast$-autonomous category:

> A *$\ast$-autonomous category* is a symmetric closed monoidal category $(C,\otimes,I,\multimap)$ with a global dualizing object: An object $\bot$ such that the canonical morphism
> $$d_A: A \rightarrow (A \multimap \bot) \multimap \bot$$ which is the transpose of the evaluation map is an isomorphism for all $A \in C$.

Secondly, call an object $A$ in a (symmetric) monoidal category $(M,\otimes,\top)$ *invertible* if there exist an object $B \in M$, and two isomorphisms $\eta: \top\rightarrow A \otimes B$ and $\epsilon: B \otimes A \rightarrow \top$ satisfying the two zig-zag-identities.
(In fact, by an argument of Saavedra Rivano it suffices to require that only one zig-zag identity holds, but that is beside the point.)

**2. Question**
What are ('real-world') examples of $\ast$-autonomous categories with non-invertible global dualizing object?

Comment: What unit and counit are you asking to be invertible?

Comment: The OP is referring to the general notion of a dualizable object in a monoidal category (which is not the same as a dualizing object): https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable+object

Comment: The constructible category of sheaves on a singular variety might be an example, there doesn’t seem to be obvious dualising maps for the dualising sheaf.

Comment: @ChrisH Is that category $\ast$-autonomous?  I didn't know that.

Comment: It is! I don’t have a reference off hand, but one can prove it without much trouble using the six functor formalism and that duality respects external products.

Comment: @ChrisH Cool! That might be the most "naturally-occurring" $\ast$-autonomous category I've ever encountered.  It would be great to have that as an example on the nLab (hint, hint)...

Comment: (I mean, other than categories that are compact closed and hence degenerately $\ast$-autonomous.  The other contender is suplattices, of course.)

Comment: @MikeShulman Another contender is, for a finite-dimensional (associative, unital) algebra $A$ over a field $k$, the category of finite-dimensional $A$-bimodules. This becomes a monoidal category via the tensor product over $A$. The linear dual $A^*$ is a dualizing object.

Comment: @MaxDemirdilek Is that tensor product symmetric?

Comment: @MikeShulman No, not in general. But in my book a $\ast$-autonomous category isn’t required to be symmetric monoidal. (I simply used the nLab-reference out of convenience.)

Comment: Well, if you quote a definition in your question saying that it's symmetric, you shouldn't be surprised if people only give you answers that are symmetric... (-:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dualizing object of a star-autonomous category is invertible iff the category is compact closed. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284805/uniqueness-of-dualizing-objects?rq=1).

There are lots of examples of star-autonomous categories which are not compact closed. In algebraic geometry, one systematically constructs dualizing sheaves which are not generally invertible -- some of this is alluded to in the comments.

In homotopy theory, the category of spectra of finite type is a good example. The dualizing object is the [Anderson dualizing spectrum](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Anderson+duality) $I_{\mathbb Z}$.