# Examples of $\ast$-autonomous $(\infty,1)$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, infinity-categories, monoidal-categories, duality, linear-logic

A *$\ast$-autonomous category* is a biclosed monoidal category together with a dualizing object. An object $\bot$ in a biclosed monoidal category $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ with left internal hom $[-,-]$ is called a *dualizing object* if the functor $[-,\bot] \colon \mathcal{C}^{op}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ is an equivalence.

This immediately suggests the notion of a $\ast$-autonomous $(\infty,1)$-category:

> Call an object $\bot$ in a biclosed monoidal $(\infty,1)$-category $\mathcal{C}$ with left internal hom $[-,-]$ a *dualizing object* if the $(\infty,1)$-functor $[-,\bot]:\mathcal{C}^{op} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ is an equivalence. A *$\ast$-autonomous category* is a biclosed monoidal $(\infty,1)$-category together with a dualizing object.

As I learned from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430376/ast-autonomous-categories-with-non-invertible-dualizing-object), a certain subcategory of the stable $(\infty,1)$-category of spectra seems to be an example of a $\ast$-autonomous $(\infty,1)$-category. The [Anderson spectrum](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Anderson+duality) is a dualizing object.

Are there other naturally occurring $\ast$-autonomous $(\infty,1)$-categories?

Comment: I assume you mean other than the "trivial" case of compact closed $(\infty,1)$-categories.  In that direction, I presume there must be an $\infty$-Chu construction...

Comment: @MikeShulman By a "compact closed $(\infty,1)$-category" do you mean a symmetric monoidal $(\infty,1)$-category whose homotopy category is compact closed? If so, you assume correctly :-) Your comment makes me wonder whether your results from *$\ast$-Autonomous Envelopes and Conservativity* extend to the $(\infty,1)$-categorical setting …

Comment: Good question; I haven't thought about it.